# CocoaPods could not find compatible versions for pod "React/Core"?

Tags: ios, swift, react-native

Following the steps in the link doesn't help in integrating react native in existing project.

Link:
https://reactnative.dev/docs/integration-with-existing-apps

**Configuration**

```
Mac OS X - 10.15.6 (19G2021)
XCode - 12.1 (12A7403)
React Native Cli - 2.0.1
React Native - 0.63.4
```

**package.json**

```
{
  "name": "MyReactNativeApp",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "start": "yarn react-native start"
  }
  "dependencies": {
    "react-native": "^0.63.4"
  }
}
```

**Podfile**

```
source 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git'

# Required for Swift apps
platform :ios, '11.0'
use_frameworks!

# The target name is most likely the name of your project.
target 'MyReactNativeApp' do
  
  # Your 'node_modules' directory is probably in the root of your project,
  # but if not, adjust the `:path` accordingly
  pod 'React', :path => '../MyReactNativeApp/node_modules/react-native', :subspecs => [
  'Core',
  'CxxBridge', # Include this for RN >= 0.47
  'DevSupport', # Include this to enable In-App Devmenu if RN >= 0.43
  'RCTText',
  'RCTNetwork',
  'RCTWebSocket', # needed for debugging
  # Add any other subspecs you want to use in your project
  ]
  # Explicitly include Yoga if you are using RN >= 0.42.0
  pod "Yoga", :path => "../MyReactNativeApp/node_modules/react-native/ReactCommon/yoga"
  
  # Third party deps podspec link
  pod 'DoubleConversion', :podspec => '../MyReactNativeApp/node_modules/react-native/third-party-podspecs/DoubleConversion.podspec'
  pod 'glog', :podspec => '../MyReactNativeApp/node_modules/react-native/third-party-podspecs/glog.podspec'
  pod 'Folly', :podspec => '../MyReactNativeApp/node_modules/react-native/third-party-podspecs/Folly.podspec'
  
end
```

When I run pod install. I get an error

```
[!] CocoaPods could not find compatible versions for pod "React/Core":
```

**Screenshot:**

[image]

I checked existing threads. Nothing works fine. I also did pod 'React' by removing everything else, result is

1. It's deprecated
2. It's not detected as Module. Module not found - I
   will separate Question for that.

Comment: Did you try `pod update`?

Comment: Yes, I did try, but no use.

Comment: Why don't you check its compatibility before trying to install it?

Comment: As its done as per mentioned in their official documentation. If I do remove them, or change compatibility, Other issues arrives. I posted another question where I removed all subspec & used React, which mention its deprecated with respective errors. @ElTomato

Comment: Oops...  It was my misunderstanding.  I thought you were trying to use it for macOS.  I'm sorry about that.

Comment: Its okay. 

This is an existing App in pure Swift where I am trying to use React Native. Whole documentation seems either out-dated or worthless to be followed.

Answer (score 0):

Follow these steps. It might help.

- Open your project in XCode.
- Expand `Pods` file.
- There should be `Development Pods`, expand it also.
- Find `React` folder. There should be 2 folders: `Pods` and `Support Files`. Go to `Pods` folder.
- This directory should contain `React.podspec` file, open it, find where is `s.dependency "React/Core",` and change to `s.dependency "React-Core",`.

Comment: This error comes during pod install command. Pod folder won't be generated. I am trying to add into existing project. Please revisit question.

Comment: If you mean to change inside react modules, question is why such library in official repo which doesn’t exist for new version. I did that but it causes more problems subsequently

Comment: Currently its   s.dependency "React-Core", version

Comment: While pod install detects "React/Core":

Comment: When I did 

  pod 'React', :path => '../MyReactNativeApp/node_modules/react-native'
  pod 'React-Core', :path => '../MyReactNativeApp/node_modules/react-native'


It says 

[!] Unable to find a specification for `React-RCTActionSheet (= 0.63.4)` depended upon by `React`

Comment: Maybe another `.podspec` contains `"React/Core"`. Try this command to change if some exists. `grep -rl "s.dependency 'React/Core'" node_modules/ | xargs sed -i '' 's=React/Core=React-Core=g'`

Comment: Nothing changed. It's same. 

[!] CocoaPods could not find compatible versions for pod "React/Core":
  In Podfile:
    React/Core (from `../MyReactNativeApp/node_modules/react-native`)

None of your spec sources contain a spec satisfying the dependency: `React/Core (from `../MyReactNativeApp/node_modules/react-native`)`.